# NHibernate with nothing but stored procedures

Tags: c#, nhibernate, stored-procedures, nhibernate-mapping

I'd like to have NHibernate call a stored procedure when ISession.Get is called to fetch an entity by its key instead of using dynamic SQL.

We have been using NHibernate and allowing it to generate our SQL for queries and inserts/updates/deletes, but now may have to deploy our application to an environment that requires us to use stored procedures for all database access.  We can use sql-insert, sql-update, and sql-delete in our .hbm.xml mapping files for inserts/updates/deletes.  Our hql and criteria queries will have to be replaced with stored procedure calls.

However, I have not figured out how to force NHibernate to use a custom stored procedure to fetch an entity by its key.  I still want to be able to call ISession.Get, as in:

```
using (ISession session = MySessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    return session.Get<Customer>(customerId);
}
```

and also lazy load objects, but I want NHibernate to call my "GetCustomerById" stored procedure instead of generating the dynamic SQL.

Can this be done?

Perhaps NHibernate is no longer a fit given this new environment we must support.

Comment: Honestly you really need to change the environment, these stored proc requirements are absolutely asinine, they offer no security and performance benefits and could easily add weeks if not months of developers hours to your project. This sounds like entirely a management defect.

Comment: I have to agree with Chris. I don't know if it's it is a management decision, but using SP for the sake of using it is not exactly good practice from several perspectives.

Comment: I'm in agreement over SPs being a bad way to go.  I introduced NH to get away from writing hundreds of stored procs and boost our productivity and it has been great.  It is seen by somebody at the customer's site as a security requirement to prevent SQL injection I assume.  It may be management, a DBA, infrastructure/IT, but I have not been able to communicate with the ultimate decision maker.  Obviously SQL injection can still be a problem in SPs that contain dynamic SQL, so the policy may be producing a false sense of security.

Comment: Why would you do it when you know how stupid it is? I would refuse to do it.

Comment: An occasional sproc one off is one thing, but if you want NHibernate to use sprocs for each operation, even if you could, why would you want to? Don't... just... don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not tried it myself but you might want to looking into [native sql and custom loader](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-load) concept.

Here's a good article by Ayende Rahien: [Using NHibernate With Stored Procedures](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/18/UsingNHibernateWithStoredProcedures.aspx)

Here's another easier-to-understand version by Scott McMaster based on NH beta version: [Stored Procedures in NHibernate](http://softwaredevscott.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!1A9E939F7373F3B7!241.entry)

Comment: Thanks for the info. It looks like the loader idea is what I was looking for and being a newbie to NH I didn't know about it yet.  Some good news: the project we're working on right now won't be deployed to the restricted environment so for the time being we're going to let NH create the SQL.