# Can you load nhibernate entities from a stored procedure, will associates be loaded also?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Is it possible to load nhibernate entities from a stored procedure?

If yes, Will it lazy load the associatations also or will it be more like a sessionless connection?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481494/nhibernate-with-nothing-but-stored-procedures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, you can read more about it here: http://ayende.com/blog/1692/using-nhibernate-with-stored-procedures

It's been a while since I used this but I as far as I can remember, associations will be lazy loaded as usual.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can,
you will do everything the same, columns definitions ... just replace your the table name with your view name using the WithTable method:

WithTable("myTableView");

or

Table("myTableView");

not sure if nhibernate is same as fluent nhibernate

Comment: Fluent NHibernate is 3rd party fluent API for configuration of NHibernate specifically around the class to db table mappings.